# Using PubNub with RhoMobile

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes, pubnub

I've done some proof of concept work which would indicate to me that PubNub should work with RhoMobile.  Has anyone else implemented this?  I'm specifically looking to use PubNub as a replacement for PUSH messaging.

Obviously, PubNub won't work when the app is not running, but other than that limitation - what else should I be looking out for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the app is not running, your data is queued in History.  Use the History API to check what was missed while the app not running: http://www.pubnub.com/tutorial/history-api-tutorial

Note that if the app IS running and the 3G connection is dropped, upon reconnect data will be received automatically.

I will be in touch with Rhomobile and ask about this!